# apache is utilizing 100% of cpu usage on m3.xlarge ec2 instance running centos - how to tune apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, amazon-ec2, httpd

I have recently migrated to amazon. I have m3.xlarge maching with 4 cpu cores and 15 GB RAM .
But my site goes down suddenly due to 100 % cpu utilization.

top command says apache is utilizing almost 99 % cpu.

I tried to tune apache for performance but had no success, I don't have good knowledge of apache tuning.

Please help me tune the apache so that cpu is choking is avoided.
this is the current set up of my apache

```
Timeout 1200
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 150
KeepAliveTimeout 100

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers      5
MinSpareServers   5
MaxSpareServers   10
ServerLimit      150
MaxClients       150
MaxRequestsPerChild  500
</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         30
MinSpareThreads     7
MaxSpareThreads     15 
ThreadsPerChild     15
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

I think these parameters are needed to optimize, any suggestions depending upon my configuration?

Update: I have mysql running on different machine of same configuration (m3.xlarge)

Comment: The typical problem is not as much Apache itself but whatever web application is running.

Comment: its your app not apache

Comment: I had comparatively low configuration previously where such problems never appeared. Are you sure my apache settings are upto the mark?

Comment: The apache settings being good or bad depends on the number of hits you get and the server configuration. There is no one good, works-for-all apache settings. The reason why apache is using up a lot of CPU could be the application that you are running, and not apache itself.

Comment: How are you rendering php?

Comment: @peter, I don't understand what you mean by "rendering php", my site is running on prestashop version 1.5.6

Comment: Unless you are using worker MPM, remove the extra configs to avoid confusion.  If your server is getting crushed, keep cutting MaxClients in half until things are better.  Also look at your app's performance with some analysis tool like New Relic.

Comment: Check your logs: Likely at: /var/log/apache2/access.log /var/log/apache2/error.log /var/log/apache2/yoursitename_access.log What sort of apps are you running... cpu is likely cranking on the app, not the core apache logic.